# Youtube-API: Where do I find how many searches I already did with a key?

Tags: youtube-api

it's a very simple question, but I just can't find it.

I have a API-Key to use the Youtube-API and I know there are limitations. But where can I find how many I already did?

I went to:

https://console.developers.google.com/project

and I see my key under API & auth -> Credentials, but no data or way to look it up. Does someone know?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this URL:

[https://console.developers.google.com/project/[PROJECT_ID]/apiui/api](https://console.developers.google.com/project/%5bPROJECT_ID%5d/apiui/api)

Replacing [PROJECT_ID] with the unique number assigned to your project. The right-hand pane should list all the APIs you've authorized for your project, along with the percentage of quota it's used for the day for that API.

Comment: Thank you very much, another way to see the quota is:
Developers-Console -> Project -> API -> API&Auth -> Youtube API v3.0 -> Quota